# Can I use barebox network booting without TFTP (NFS only)?

Tags: linux, bootloader

Context: Busybox Network-Boot of Embedded Linux targets at software developer PCs

Current approach, as usual: Load kernel by TFTP, start kernel with NFS (to connect rootfs)

Question: Can I use NFS also during the very first TFTP-Step and use only NFS for everything ? In other words, can barebox network boot without TFTP ?

Reason: The developers are using Windows PCs. TFTPD and Windows aren't the best friends when I have to avoid 3d party software (even in docker/wsl2).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, barebox can boot from NFS. The default `net` target, as you've noticed, loads kernel and device tree/initrd via TFTP then lets the kernel do the NFS boot. You can use NFS (UDP only) form barebox directly by issuing either `boot /mnt/nfs` or `boot nfs://`. See [the documentation for further info](https://www.barebox.org/doc/latest/filesystems/nfs.html).